# Allow surrounding div's click event only to trigger when inner tags are not clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I've prepared a fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/9m4bgyq8/16/

As you can see, I am trying to surround a checkbox + label with a div, and apply a click-event to the div, which is only supposed to trigger when the input or label are NOT being clicked. I even applied a fakeClick-function here, which basically does nothing, and tried to suppress bubbling, however it doesn't help.

It's executing the divs function no matter what I click.

For everyone who wants to see crucial code here:

```
<ul>
  <div data-bind="click: clickFunction">
    <input id="muteCheckBox" type="checkbox" data-bind="click: fakeClick, clickbubble: false"/>
    <label for="muteCheckBox" data-bind="click: fakeClick, clickbubble: false">I'm a label</label>
  </div>
</ul>
```

and

```
var functionWrapper= {
    clickFunction : function(data, event) {
        window.alert("Event triggered");
    },
    fakeClick : function(data,event) {
        //Do nothing
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(functionWrapper);
```

It's not obvious to see here due to CSS being missing, but basically my div contains an input and label tag, and I want only the inputs and labels tag function to execute when a click is placed there, not the divs function.

Right now, the inputs and labels function are not executed at all.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your fiddle the problem is a mispelled keyword.
Look at the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9m4bgyq8/18/) and notice the "clickBubble" instead of the "clickbubble".

Another way to do that could also be calling the function stopPropagation on the event inside the fakeClick function:

```
fakeClick : function(data,event)
{
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Your modified fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9m4bgyq8/17/)

For more info about the stopPropagation look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp)

Comment: That seems to work, I'll give it a try. Do you know why clickBubble is doing nothing in this case? According to knockouts doc it should prevent bubbling, right?

Comment: My answer is working but is wrong using knockout!
I'll update my answer and the fiddle. You forgot the camelCase!